# Breathing effect using a shift register

Tags: atmega, shift-register

I want to create a breathing effect but I have 16 RGB LEDs. I also want to arrange these 16 LEDs in a square.

I plan on using a 74HC595 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf?) shift register and an Atmega32 MCU. I have figured out how to create effects like the chasing LED (not dimming them, just running the present RGB off and the next one on) effect or the rainbow (again not dimming, just switching between red, green and blue randomly per RGB) effect using the Atmega32 MCU and the 74HC595. However now I want to create a breathing effect.

I was thinking of sending a PWM (with varying duty cycles) to the Output Enable pin of the 74HC595, in order to achieve the breathing effect. Will this work?

But I would like some advice/help on this. What can I do to achieve this breathing effect?

Below is high level picture for the arrangement

[image]

Comment: @jsotola I have added a drawing

Comment: do you want all of the LEDs to "breathe" at the same time? .... try modifying the chasing effect program

Comment: @jsotola you confused me now, lol, drew the drawing incorrectly. But yes all at the same time

Comment: @jsotola the chasing effect is just turning the present RGB off and the next RGB on, it is not dimming them

Comment: you can test your theory expetimentally on a breadboard ... connect the OE to HIGH and then to LOW ... do the LEDs respond as expected? ... it is not possible to guess the outcome, because your circuit is unknown

Comment: So you just want all LEDs to fade on an off once every couple of seconds? Just to confuse you more, twenty LEDs arranged in a square will have six per side! (Your sketch of 12 LEDs has four per side.)

Comment: yes, but the chasing effect turns the LEDs on for a short time ... the code is a type of PWM ... try chase red,black,black,black at maximum speed ... that should produce 25% duty cycle

Comment: @Transistor okay I get :) I cannot count. It was suppose to 16 RGB LEDs I have updated the post, not every seconds so 500ms to fade in and 300ms fade out

Comment: THe array is meaningless as they are all in parallel and equivalent to 1 LED. So you make the question a better one , define the unknowns like the mathematical or graphical characteristics of "Breathing" with variables   or Is it just an asymmetrical triangle wave between a and b frequency ?  Please improve your design question.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 thanks for info, just for info and learning, you mentioned transfer functions in your comment in the answer below. How do I define transfer functions for this application and how do I even begin to apply it?

Comment: Manually Model the visual effects by testing then draw a plot of the current waveform that matches your expectations. Then curve fit by some regression equation, then decide how easiest to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PWM on the OE pin should work to control the LED brightness as expected. Just make the PWM duty grow from 0 to 100% and back to 0% slowly, or just select whatever duty cycles and speeds you like.

Please note that human eyes are not linear, so ramping the PWM duty linearly won't look linear to human eyes. Also the PWM frequency should be high enough not to be irritating like some car lights are.

Comment: "Please note that human eyes are not linear, so ramping the PWM duty linearly won't look linear to human eyes" that sounds interesting, havent heard of this before can you elaborate or provide a source so I can read up or watch a vid, PLEASE....?

Comment: Not too hard to search or actually find it out by PWMing a LED.

Comment: There should be thousands of articles on how to do this for Arduino and there's https://arduino.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Argh our human eyes perceive light as a logarithmic function rather than a linear. Thanks for the info

Comment: My concept to use 20 LEDs is a 6x6 square with just a PWM modulate by the the slow breathing of a sawtooth.  Of course transfer functions need to  be defined for visual response, but this accurately defines the 20P LEDs using 3.3V with 0.6Hz sawtooth modulating the PWM  . This provides more design insights to a question void of specs https://tinyurl.com/yys85xo4 yet need more work to be viable

Comment: rev 2works better https://tinyurl.com/y4t9gxrh  (slow motion)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 you got two circuits in your link, which one are you referring two?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I think I can just use a 555 TImer to achieve the PWMing of the OE pin instead of using the circuit in your link

Comment: @JoeyB why on earth would you add an 555 as the Atmega32 you are using already contains timers with hardware PWM output pins? How would you even adjust the PWM duty of the 555?

Comment: @Justme  I was supposed to type Sawtooth generator. The reason why I would prefer using an external circuit is due to processing power, you are correct I can just use the internal timer, however, I must also read in data, then process it, then set the right data to shift to the shift register, latch the data and then do the PWM. I suspect this will end up causing flickering in the breathing effect, hence I rather have a external circuit or hardware solution than a software solution

Comment: @Justme I will still test both ways (software and hardware). However, a 555 timer is so cheap so it's not going to affect me and is readily available :)

Comment: @JoeyB The PWM in the Atmega *is* a hardware solution.

Comment: @Justme but is it initialized by software and controlled by software. is it not?

Comment: @JoeyB It is, and once it has been started PWM is generated by the timer hardware with no further software interaction.

Comment: @Justme okay will try it out and see which is better, this is going to be fun!